# How to create a launch intent for CompassActivity.java class file?

Tags: activity-lifecycle

I have a compass class file that I want to launch as a fragment on a activity_main layout XML file.

What I have tried:

- multiple activities tutorial
- intent tutorial
- activities linking tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this one more time:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Additionally you may want to create it as a fragment activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I read the part on fragments and it helped clear my concept. The term "subset of activity" now makes sense in my case.